# Test frequency of outcome between two treatments when for one treatment it's 0

Tags: r, logistic, statistical-significance

I have an experiment where groups received either one of two treatments over several rounds, and I observe whether an outcome happens for a group at any given round. The outcome is thus binary, it either happens or not.

I would like to test the hypothesis that the outcome happens more frequently under treatment 1 than under treatment 2. I would generally fit a logit/probit model and test whether the coefficient linked to treatment 1 is positive and significant. However, the problem is that in my data the outcome happened 0 times for treatment 2. Is there a way I can test whether the difference between the two treatments is significant? I am using R studio as software.

Below I constructed a reduced form of my data; in reality I have 20 groups playing over 10 rounds.

```
group <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", 
           "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")
round <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
t1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
t2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
outcome <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

df <- data.frame(group, round, t1, t2, outcome)
df
```

```
   group round t1 t2 outcome
1      A     1  1  0       1
2      B     1  1  0       1
3      C     1  1  0       0
4      D     1  1  0       1
5      E     1  1  0       0
6      F     1  1  0       0
7      G     1  0  1       0
8      H     1  0  1       0
9      I     1  0  1       0
10     J     1  0  1       0
11     K     1  0  1       0
12     L     1  0  1       0
13     A     2  1  0       0
14     B     2  1  0       1
15     C     2  1  0       1
16     D     2  1  0       1
17     E     2  1  0       0
18     F     2  1  0       1
19     G     2  0  1       0
20     H     2  0  1       0
21     I     2  0  1       0
22     J     2  0  1       0
23     K     2  0  1       0
24     L     2  0  1       0
```

```
df %>% 
  group_by(t2) %>% 
  summarise(t2_mean = mean(outcome),
            t2_sd = sd(outcome))
```

`````
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     t2 t2_mean t2_sd
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1     0   0.583 0.515
2     1   0     0   

````
`````

Comment: Hint:  what procedures test for different breakdowns of counts between different groups?

Comment: @rolando2 I tried researching it but have honestly no idea I'm afraid. Any additional hint?